# Dynamics 365: Change default value of routecase field to FALSE

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I want to change default value of Route Case field on incident to False. When an incident is created from activity, this field is by default set to True and incident is routed to appropriate queue. But we want to route case only if user clicks on Save & Route button. When I try from customization settings to change default value of routecase to False, it turns back to True. Does anyone can help how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In plugin:

1.Get Target

Entity target = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

2.Set default value for Route Case

target["Route Case Name"]=false;

3.Register in pre-operation step.